# How to set a class with new properties in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to apply a certain class with certain properties.
So I have this class :

```
.k-plus::before {
  content: '\E601';
}
```

In the template I want to set a condition :

```
if(variable === 0)(*ngIf)
```

apply the  class `.k-plus::before`  to :

```
.k-plus::before {
      content: '';
    }
```

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use class binding like

```
<div [class.k-plus]="variable === 0"
```

which adds the class `k-plus` when `variable === 0` and otherwise removes it.

Comment: Hi , the idea is that I have a kendo grid and i want to remove the +/- sign if a row has no children

Comment: you can bind icon with ngIF like <icon name="plus" *ngIf="variable === 0">  <icon name="minus" *ngIf="variable !== 0">